# Terraform is giving me Fileset IDENT error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to upload multiple files to an S3 bucket as shown in this [article](https://linoxide.com/tools/upload-files-to-s3-using-terraform/) which theres also a video in it, here is the code that i use

```
# Create a bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b1" {
  bucket = "s3-terraform-bucket-labbb"
  acl    = "private"   # or can be "public-read"
  tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object1" {
    for_each = fileset("myfiles/", "*")
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.b1.id
    key = each.value
    source = "myfiles/${each.value}"
    etag = filemd5("myfiles/${each.value}")
}
```

Buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:

  install:
    commands:
      - "apt install unzip -y"
      - "wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.14/terraform_0.11.14_linux_amd64.zip"
      - "unzip terraform_0.11.14_linux_amd64.zip"
      - "mv terraform /usr/local/bin/"
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - terraform init

  build:
    commands:
      - terraform $TF_COMMAND -auto-approve

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo terraform $TF_COMMAND completed on `date`
```

When i run the TF template in codebuild, i'd get this error

`Error: Error parsing /codebuild/output/src634819119/src/s3bucket.tf: At 12:16: Unknown token: 12:16 IDENT fileset`

Anyone know if i missed anything or if theres a problem with Terraform? Thanks!

Comment: The error is from `codebuild`. Are you using TF in codebuild? Can yo should your buildspec.yml file?

Comment: @Marcin yes i do use TF in codebuild and i have the buildspec.yml, i updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **very old terraform** (0.11.14). [Current version](https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html) is 0.14.7. Despite using the old version, your terraform code is modern and thus will not work with version 0.11.

You either have to re-write your code to be valid with version 0.11, or what would be better, to **upgrade your terraform** version.

Comment: i tried to replace the terraform 0.11.14 to 0.14.7 in the builspec.yml earlier today and i got this error instead "Error: Invalid legacy provider address

This configuration or its associated state refers to the unqualified provider
"archive".

You must complete the Terraform 0.13 upgrade process before upgrading to later
versions."

Comment: @JackRogers Seems you  already have some tf state in code build. You have to check if your deployment package does not contain pre existing state from old tf versions.

Comment: ahh so, does that mean i have to completely wipe tfstate generated by my code build (they are located in dynamodb and s3) then re run the pipeline from scratch??

Comment: @JackRogers You don't have to, but you have to upgrade gradually. From 0.11 to 0.12, from 0.12 to 0.13, and from 0.13 to 0.14. Check by using 0.12 only. Your syntax should be fine for 0.12.

Comment: but if i were to wipe tfstate and start from scratch right after changing my 0.11.14 to 0.14.7, in theory that would work and sounds easier yes?

Comment: @JackRogers You will loos track of existing resource managed by TF if you have any. Depends on your setup. Are you managing production level resources, or is this project for just testing and learning purposes so you can do what you want with it? Sadly, I have no answer to this.

Comment: this is just testing and learning purposes, I'm learning so i can be good at TF, so it is okay to lose track of existing resources

Comment: @JackRogers It would be better to delete them first. If you delete the state, the resources will still exist, but TF will be not aware of them. So if you can, just start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `${path.module}` in the file path. It's recommended in
[Terraform Official docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/fileset.html). It has some good examples too.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "object1" {
    for_each = fileset("${path.module}/myfiles/", "*")
    bucket = aws_s3_bucket.b1.id
    key = each.value
    source = "myfiles/${each.value}"
    etag = filemd5("myfiles/${each.value}")
}
```

Comment: should i keep "${path.module}" as is or what do i need to change that to?